# Why the url after the getRequestDispatcher(url).forward(request,response) is different to the original?

Tags: jsp, url, servlets, requestdispatcher

When I use `getRequestDispatcher(url).forward(request,response)` the url changes to the Servlet and not to the original, why?

For example:
(Current url: http://localhost:8080/ProjectX/index.jsp)

```
<form action="/ServletX">...</form>
```

When I do: `getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp").forward(request,response)`

In the browser the URL is http://localhost:8080/ProjectX/ServletX

Why that? It's good or has an error?

(I think the url maybe the same before the form was submitted index.jsp)

Thanks,

Comment: when you submit the form , the url will be `http://localhost:8080/ProjectX/ServletX`,

Comment: bcoz your form has `action="/ServletX"` , so when you submit the form it will send data to whatever you specified in `action`